# Youtube .NET API v3 search

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using Google YouTube .NET API version 3. I added following nuget packages

As given in the Youtube developer example, I can search in content or title but i can't search in video tag. Can i search by specific tag ? Have any examples or codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question answer:

[According to their documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={API-key}&fields=items(snippet(title,description,tags))&part=snippet&id={video_id}`